# Automated string pattern matching in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

My client wants to categorize a free-text column in one of their tables by recognizing a specific string pattern ('AAA', 'BBB',...) in the column field name. They provided me with a query to do the categorization:

```
SELECT  [Column],
CASE 
 WHEN UPPER([Column]) LIKE '%AAA%' 
   OR UPPER([Column]) LIKE '%BBB%'
   OR UPPER([Column]) LIKE '%CCC%' 
   OR UPPER([Column]) LIKE '%DDD%' 
   OR UPPER([Column]) LIKE '%EEE%'  
 THEN 'Category1'
 WHEN UPPER([Column]) LIKE '%FFF%' 
   OR UPPER([Column]) LIKE '%GGG%' 
   OR UPPER([Column]) LIKE '%HHH%' 
 THEN 'Category2'
 WHEN UPPER([Column]) LIKE '%III%' 
   OR UPPER([Column]) LIKE '%JJJ%'  
 THEN 'Category3'
 WHEN UPPER([Column]) LIKE '%KKK%'
   OR UPPER([Column]) LIKE '%LLL%'
   OR UPPER([Column]) LIKE '%MMM%'
 THEN 'Category4' END TYPE
FROM [Table]
```

This works fine, but the issue is that they want to add more patterns in the future and they don't have access to the source code. So they want to be able to upload their patterns through a flat file which will get extracted and stored in a table like this:

```
+-------+-----------+---------+
| Level | Category  | Pattern |
+-------+-----------+---------+
|     1 | Category1 | AAA     |
|     1 | Category1 | BBB     |
|     1 | Category1 | CCC     |
|     1 | Category1 | DDD     |
|     1 | Category1 | EEE     |
+-------+-----------+---------+
|     2 | Category2 | FFF     |
|     2 | Category2 | GGG     |
|     2 | Category2 | HHH     |
+-------+-----------+---------+
|     3 | Category3 | III     |
|     3 | Category3 | JJJ     |
+-------+-----------+---------+
|     4 | Category4 | KKK     |
|     4 | Category4 | LLL     |
|     4 | Category4 | MMM     |
+-------+-----------+---------+
```

So now I am trying to figure out if there is any automated way of designing the CASE WHEN statement from above (with T-SQL or scripting) using the Pattern table as input. The order of the CASE WHEN is also very important and that is why I added the 'Level' column.

SSIS will be used to assign the category to every row in the table. Are there any components in SSIS to help me accomplish my goal?

Comment: In SSIS you have access to both `String.Contains` and `Regex` in a scripting component, so you can read in the table and use that. You can also still do this from regular T-SQL, using `CROSS APPLY`, but that query's going to be fairly ugly.

Comment: Do you want a query that will dynamically create the CASE statement each time it runs, or a script that can be run to create the SELECT/CASE statement, and that statement is then saved to be run as needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have 2 different solutions you can use with TSQL.

1) Looping updates (faster). I assume that `Category` on `[Table]` is null before updating.

```
DECLARE @MaxLevel INT = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(Level), 0) FROM Category)

DECLARE @LevelIterator INT = 1

WHILE @LevelIterator <= @MaxLevel
BEGIN

    UPDATE T SET
        Category = C.Category
    FROM
        [Table] AS T
        INNER JOIN Category AS C ON UPPER(T.[Column]) LIKE '%' + C.Pattern + '%'
    WHERE
        C.Level = @LevelIterator AND
        T.Category IS NULL

    SET @LevelIterator += 1

END
```

2) Massive update (slower)

```
;WITH MinimumLevelMatch AS
(
    SELECT
        T.[Column],
        MinLevel = MIN(C.Level)
    FROM
        [Table] AS T
        INNER JOIN Category AS C ON UPPER(T.[Column]) LIKE '%' + C.Pattern + '%'
    GROUP BY
        T.[Column]
),
CategoryByLevel AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        C.Level,
        C.Category
    FROM
        Category AS C
)
UPDATE T SET
    Category = C.Category
FROM
    [Table] AS T
    INNER JOIN MinimumLevelMatch AS M ON T.[Column] = M.[Column]
    INNER JOIN CategoryByLevel AS C ON M.MinLevel = C.Level
```

Try to avoid using SSIS to implement business logics. Use it to it's main purpose, *integrating systems*.